# transform scale on child causes abnormal overflow scroll appearance?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-transforms

Why does the vertical scrollbar double in size in this example, but not the horizontal scrollbar?

```
<div style="width:200px; height: 200px; overflow:scroll">
  <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px; background-color:orange; transform: scale(.5, .5); -webkit-transform: scale(.5, .5); transform-origin: 0 0; -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;">
    TEST TEXT 1 TEST TEXT 2 TEST TEXT 3 TEST TEXT 4 TEST TEXT 5 TEST TEXT 6 TEST TEXT 7 TEST TEXT 8
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The horizontal scrollbar should have the same ratio as the vertical scrollbar.

As it happens in chrome, safari, and firefox I am guessing this behavior is written up in some standard?
Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/v2xhj3kw/

Comment: you mention horizontal twice in your post... please clarify which you meant as vertical...

Answer (score 0):

The box model is adding properties to the parent element

```
height: auto;
```

is the property that is causing the increase in height.

Comment: adding height:auto to the child removes the vertical scrollbar altogether -- i am trying to make the horizontal scrollbar have the same ratio as the vertical scrollbar